# Remove square bracket from println (Android/Klaxon)

Tags: android, json, klaxon

Check [this](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#pretty-printing) from the documentation of Klaxon. With `toJsonString(true)` I can remove the `JsonArray(value=[...]`. But the square brackets are still there. Is there another way to remove **everything**? I just want to print the value.

Before `toJsonString(true)`:

```
JsonArray(value=[ValueOfJSON])
```

After `toJsonString(true)`:

```
["ValueOfJSON"]
```

That's what I want:

```
"ValueOfJSON"
```

Comment: What is return type of toJsonString(true) method?

Comment: It's `String` @AndroidTeam

Comment: A simple hackaround is: your_string_name.split('"')[1]

Comment: Dude, that's awesome! Thank you! @dustblue

Comment: Not a problem ;)

Comment: Another solution is your_string_name.replace("[","").replace("]","");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple hackaround is:

```
your_string_name.split('"')[1]
```